# Why I'm getting this memory leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, instruments, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak with instruments at this line:

```
NSString * finalString;
finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",chunksString];
```

chunksString is declared as class field NSString.

Is initialized in other method as:

```
chunksString =  [NSString stringWithString:@""];
```

And in other method takes the value:

```
chunksString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",chunksString,string];
```

Instruments tells a leak of 100% in the line where finalString is filled.

As I understand chunksString is never initialized with alloc, copy or init same as finalString. Both aren't properties with retain, why I'm having this leak?

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's finalString that's leaking the new NSString assigned to it. Are you releasing that later in the code?

Comment: @Joachim - how a factory method creating a leak? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",chunksString];

Comment: when you say "chunkString is declared as class field NSString" what exactly do you mean by that? Is it a property? In that case strings should be declared with copy and not retain and addressed with self.chunkString and in the dealloc assigned to nil. Are you doing that?

Comment: assign to nil when declare NSString * finalString = nil;

Comment: Are you using an autorelease pool? stringWithFormat registers the string in the autorelease pool if one exists, so if you have one, I can't see the reason for the warning from just that line of code.

Comment: Hi, It's declared as chunksString is declared in the implementation as a field of the class. Is not declared as property.

Comment: BTW, the code `chunksString =  [NSString stringWithString:@""];
` is the hard way, all that is necessary is: `chunksString = @"";`. Less code is better code.

Comment: The code `finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",chunksString];` is more concisely: `finalString = chunksString;`

Comment: The code: `chunksString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",chunksString,string];` is more concisely: `chunksString = [chunksString stringByAppendingString:string];`.

Answer (score 1):

The leak initial memory allocation is at the line:

```
finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",chunksString];
```

The leak is because further in the life of `finalString` there is a retain that is not balanced with a release. You need to look at the full lifetime of `finalString`.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the problem code to run, stop recording, search for there ivar of interest, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Better yet, use ARC if at all possible, it can be turned off for individual files if there is legacy code that can't be ported to ARC.

Comment: do you think the Analyzer would have picked up this leak?

Comment: I've done with Instruments. And the finalString var is declared in the same method where is used. Doesn't appears in other functions. Only is used in the method where is declared.

Comment: Plus one for using ARC.  There is almost no reason developers should still be trying to manage object allocation manually.

Comment: ARC supports iOS 4.x and up. There is only one component that is iOS 5 and that is weak reference zeroing, just don't use that new feature.